# Is the Thrift service running on HDInsight?

Tags: .net, azure, hbase, thrift, azure-hdinsight

I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

If the Thrift service is supposed to be running then does anyone know the port number or URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only Stargate (the REST API) is available to what is public to Azure right now.

I requested access to the Thrift service from the HDInsight team already one or two months ago, so maybe they will add this in a future release.

Comment: I've since been using the Stargate (REST Api) via [Marlin - Microsoft HBase REST Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/hdinsight/hbase-sdk-for-net)